# Static in clause sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to put more than one static in clause in the SQL (oracle) and its not working, any one has an idea or a work around it. Below is what I'm trying to do

```
select *
 from Table
where ('1', '2') in ('1', '2', '3')
```

I know it can be done using OR clause but I don't want to use it as there are too many arguments.

Comment: In words, what is the logic you would want to implement?  That the former is a subset of the latter?  If the `in` clause is really static, why add it at all?  Or do you really mean that one of the two lists (or both) are dynamically generated but not based on data stored in the database?  Why is this tagged `mysql` and `sql-server` if you're not using those databases?

Comment: first of all sorry about the tag. Any sql syntax if someone can give, I can translate it to Oracle. The right Argument is dynamically generated by the app and left is hardcoded!

Comment: And what is the logic that you're trying to implement?  That the left hand hard-coded list is a strict subset of the right hand list?  Is there a reason that you can't just do that in the query rather than running whatever query you run to get the right-hand list?

Comment: The right hand list is dynamically generated based on the user logged in. the right list is actually list of security groups a user is a member of

Comment: Do you not have a security group table to join to? And/or a security group/users table?

Comment: is the left group the values or column names? it makes no sense to select from a table and dont use a columns in a where clause.

Comment: Left group is hard coded value. It will look at the right group and if match is there then good, show the data with some other and logic if no match then the sql where clause will be 1=2 which gives no data. its just to apply the security!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guess your query is intended to flexible handle a bunch of input options and dynamically adjust the output in some way. Perhaps this is an approach that will work. Usually these BI systems are going to still want a syntactically valid query so unfortunately you can't build the whole query dynamically.

```
with list(val) as (
    select val from master_list_of_values where val in (? /* BI_Parameter */)
)
select * from Table
where
        A in (select id from list)
    or  B in (select id from list)
```

UPDATE: Based on your edit, this will work although I don't know if it will always generate great plans:

```
with security_test(passed) as (
    select count(*) as passed
    from security_groups
    where group_id in (? /* BI_Parameter */) and group_id in (/* hard-coded list */)
)
select * from Table
where (select passed from security_test > 0)
```

You could use also hard-code the list in a `values` expression instead of using a "security_groups" table.

```
with security_test(passed) as (
    select count(*) as passed
    from (values (1), (2)) security_groups(group_id)
    where group_id in (? /* BI_Parameter */)
)
select * from Table
where (select passed from security_test > 0)
```

Here's another thought...

```
with security_test(passed) as (
    select count(*) as passed
    from (values (1), (2)) security_groups(group_id)
    where group_id in (? /* BI_Parameter */)
    having count(*) > 0 /* will this collapse to zero rows? */
)
select * from Table, security_test
```

Comment: the whole purpose of this question is that im trying to avoid or condition as there are many arguments :)

Comment: I like these ideas. i'll see it they will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done how you want it done, because of ambiguity.  For instance, would that syntax mean "1 and 2 are in 1,2,3" or would it mean "1 is in 1,2,3 or 2 is in 1,2,3".

I think it would really help to see what is generating this static in clause and what the actual end goal is... Then I'll edit my answer to help more.

**Edit**

I think there is just a simple logical flaw in your application design.  Would it not also work to remove the (1,2,3) clause altogether, and then rather than consider your '1,2' as static, just reference the column.  For example, this achieves what you want with a little tweaking of your (incorrectly developed) BI report:

```
select *
from Table
where  myCharColumn in ('1', '2')
```

Comment: it should mean "1 is in 1,2,3 or 2 is in 1,2,3". A BI application is generating the right argument at the IN clause [('1', '2', '3')] and the left argument [('1', '2')] is hard coded!

Comment: Then there is a flaw in application design.  What is the purpose of asking if 1 is in 1,2,3 or 2 is in 1,2,3.  Why not just ask "is my Integer in (1,2)"

Comment: the purpose is to achieve the following without OR condition.              select * from Table where '1' in ('1', '2', '3') or '2' in ('1', '2', '3')

Comment: Why are you trying to get rid of an OR condition? Do you expect a performance difference of some kind?

Comment: Performance is not the biggest concern as if I achieve it with anyother ways, under the hood Oracle might act the same way. Anyhoo, main purpose is to avoid having to type so many arguments with OR condition.

Comment: skk_cognos look at my edit and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: IN isn't going to work because the left hand side is always supposed to be one value and the right hand side is one or more values. Why is the left hand side hard coded as a static? Don't you have a column to compare to?

Comment: Exactly, I don't have a column to compare to. and yea true that left hand has to be one static or a column. im looking for an alternate way to do it. @ Philip - There is no Flaw in the App design. its just some log data and that's how it is.

Comment: Apologies but this sounds very much like a design issue. Either you need a security table to join or you need to split this into ORs or you need to write your own function to handle comparing the strings.

Comment: I agree a security table is all needed here. But as I said earlier its Audit data, don't have money to make any ETL changes. but I guess its ok if no workaround; OR is always there :)